# How to fill a array with numbers only from 0 to 20 C Language

Tags: c

I need to make a C program that asks the user to insert 5 numbers into an array, but those numbers can only be from 0 to 20 if they are bigger than 20 or smaller than 0 there needs to be an error message. I'm brando new to C, so I'm having a bit of trouble getting this done and currently i have no idea how to do it. This is my current code.

```
int i;
int media=0;
int soma=0;
```

`int notas[5]`

```
for ( i=0; i <5; i++)
{
    printf("\n Por favor insira : \t");
    scanf("%f", &notas[i]);
}

if (notas[i] < 0 || notas[i] > 20)
{
    printf("\n Por favor insira um numero de 0 a 20");
}
else
{
    soma = notas[i]+notas[i];
    media = soma/5;
}



return 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mis-using the `i` variable: After the end of the loop, its value is `5` - so you're looking at the out-of-range index 5 into the `notas` array - which isn't what you wanted.

You should:

1. Move your check (`if notas[i] < 0` etc.) into the body of the loop.
2. Repeat the `i`'th iteration if you got an invalid value.

Also, you seem to be mis-calculating the average value.